# Using Google Sheets for web scraping. Importxml function xpath correction

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use the importxml function in google sheets scrape the MPN (Manufacturer part number) from a website for a list of products (about 2000).

The website:
http://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/640832007756

The instructions said to use the importxml formula. The link is A1, then used inspector in chrome to copy the xpath. The result:

```
 =IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@id='content']/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/dl/div[2]/dd/a")
```

(Instructions also said to change double quotes to single around content.)

The error is imported "content in empty" when running the formula. I have tried to make edits and I think the XPath is incorrect. Some say that you can't copy-paste from inspector as the instructions said.

One other thing I tried was `=IMPORTHTML(A1, "list", 8)`. This returns UPC and MPN. But it puts the MPN on the second line.

I am new to this and have searched for the last couple of nights for a solution. any help would be much appreciated.

Also Bonus question. What would the formula be to scrape the UPC if we had the MPN? https://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/J941PSL9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the value of "MPN" from the value of "UPC".
- You want to retrieve the value of "UPC" from the value of "MPN".
- You want to achieve this using the built-in functions of Google Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample formula? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the value of "MPN" is retrieved from the value of "UPC".

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/"&A2,"//li[contains(text(),'MPN')]/a")
```

- the xpath is `//li[contains(text(),'MPN')]/a`.
- In this case, the value of "UPC" is put in the cell "A2".

#### Result:

[image]

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the value of "UPC" is retrieved from the value of "MPN".

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/"&A2,"//li[contains(text(),'UPC')]/a")
```

- the xpath is `//li[contains(text(),'UPC')]/a`.
- In this case, the value of "MPN" is put in the cell "A2".

#### Result:

[image]

### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

From [your replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58601028/using-google-sheets-for-web-scraping-importxml-function-xpath-correction#comment103533772_58602814), I modified the formulas for using the following values.

> Here is a list of UPC 787450038417 787450230576 661120974888 859462004015 82442306667 810237023013 798681538782 787450348196 604206120816

#### UPC --> MPN:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/"&A2,"//dd/a[../../dt[contains(text(),'UPC')]]|//dd/span[../../dt[contains(text(),'UPC')]]")
```

- the xpath is `//dd/a[../../dt[contains(text(),'UPC')]]|//dd/span[../../dt[contains(text(),'UPC')]]`.
- In this case, the value of "UPC" is put in the cell "A2".

#### MPN --> UPC:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/"&B2,"//dd/a")
```

- the xpath is `//dd/a`.
- In this case, the value of "MPN" is put in the cell "B2".

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Getting an error " Imported content is empty" on most of the items.  About 1 in 20 will pull in the MPN.  Here is a list of UPC  787450038417
787450230576
661120974888
859462004015
82442306667
810237023013
798681538782
787450348196
604206120816 <-- this one works.    The empty content error doesn't make sense because I can see the data if I visit that page.  Thank you for your help on this. It feels like we are very close.

Comment: @Planterguy Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my answer is for your question. So I confirmed about the URLs of `http://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/640832007756` and `https://gun.deals/search/apachesolr_search/J941PSL9`. But in your replying, I couldn't notice you want to also retrieve for other URLs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I have to apologize again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This will save me a lot of time.